# while I'm calling two functions on one click(onclick) only redirect function is executing.? need solution for it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know javascript that much so please help to solve this

I have tried so many ways to call two functions at a time but the details in signup is not storing in database. The SignUp() function is not working it seems.
Attaching javascript code I have return.

```js
function SignUp() {
  var name = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;


  if (password == password2) {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((res) => {
      database.ref('User/' + auth.currentUser.uid).set({
        name: name,
        password: password2,
      });
      //showhide();
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      alert(error.message);
    });

  } else {
    alert("password didnt match");
    document.querySelector('.form_container').reset();
  }

}

function redirect() {
  window.location.href = "../index.html";
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You are trying to call two functions at the same time? First, you can't do that (call two functions concurrently), second, why, and third, where? You aren't trying to call two functions at once in the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I start, just for future reference, you'll get better answers if you can post a complete and reproducible example of what's happening. It's hard to understand from your question what's causing the issue as we can't see everything we need.

There are a few different ways to call more than one function at a time on click. But really it's best to call one function directly from `onclick` - things will be easier to understand that way.

In the example below, button with text `A` and `B` each call one function.

Button with text `C` calls a single function that will then call two functions.

Button with text `D` uses an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to call the two functions directly from onclick. This could easily get confusing and I'd recommend against it in general.

```js
function fA() {
  console.log('a');
}

function fB() {
  console.log('b');
}

function fC() {
  fA();
  fB();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fA()">A</button>
<button onclick="fB()">B</button>
<button onclick="fC()">C</button>

<button onclick="(function() { fA(); fB(); })()">D</button>
```

---

As a second guess at the problem you're having, if you have code which runs asynchronously (for instance, in your example `SignUp` uses code which looks as though it returns a promise) then it will not be executed immediately. Consider this example:

```js
function registerANewUser () {
  return fetch('http://www.google.com')
    .then(() => console.log('finished making request'))
    .catch(() => console.error('error making request'));
}

function redirect() {
  console.log('redirecting...');
}

function signUp() {
  console.log('signup clicked');
  registerANewUser()
    .then(() => console.log('finished registering a new user'));
    
  redirect();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="signUp()">Sign up</button>
```

The call to `redirect` will happen immediately after the call to `registerANewUser` and will therefore happen before the log `"finished registering a new user`.

Consider solving it with async/await:

```js
function registerANewUser () {
  return fetch('http://www.google.com')
    .then(() => console.log('finished making request'))
    .catch(() => console.error('error making request'));
}

function redirect() {
  console.log('redirecting...');
}

async function signUp() {
  console.log('signup clicked');
  await registerANewUser()
    .then(() => console.log('finished registering a new user'));
    
  redirect();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="signUp()">Sign up</button>
```

If you look at the order in which things happen in that example, you'll see that the redirect only happens once the promise has resolved.

Comment: But this still calls `fA()` then `fB()`, they aren't called at the same time

Comment: @JeremyThille Indeed! Perhaps I'm being naive but I think it's ok to try and read between the lines a little on these things. You can't call two functions concurrently (as you said in your comment) so I'm not sure it's worth considering that as an option either from the perspective of the OP or the answer.

Comment: @OliverRadini, really thanks for your answers. second guess of yours matched a lot my problem. It worked but only problem is the "then" condition is not working everything else is working. I want to send you my signup.html file and related javascript file.

Comment: @I'm_not_a_genius are you hitting the code in the catch? If the code inside the `then` is not executing it means the promise is not resolving

Comment: @OliverRadini, I don't know how to send my files through comment. Is there any way to contact you if not I will describe some more details of my problem.
when user enter data in signup page and clicks signup button then we want  email and password stores in authentication database, same data has to store in realtime database(which is written in "then"), then the page has to redirect to home page. After doing modifications to code seeing your second guess "data going to authentication database and page redirecting to home base are working." But not going to realtime database written in "then"

Comment: @I'm_not_a_genius the first thing I'd do is determine what parts of the code are being hit. This will tell you what the frontend is doing and from there you can begin to debug the backend. I'd put breakpoints inside the `then` and `catch` statements to see when they're being hit. You need to open the console to have these breakpoints take effect.

Comment: @OliverRadini, I did as you said. I kept breakpoints inside `then` and `catch`. It is hitting `then`. Then I written my requirement in `then` but data is not storing in realtime database. I'm attaching small part of my code in next comment once see it.

Comment: @OliverRadini,
`  async function SignUp(){
  var name = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
  `

Comment: @OliverRadini,
`
  if(password == password2) {
      await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((res) => {
      database.ref('User/'+auth.currentUser.uid).set({
          name: name,
          password: password2,
      });
      //showhide();
      }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          alert(error.message);
      });
      redirect();
  }

  else{
      alert("password didnt match");
      document.querySelector('.form_container').reset();
  }

}
function redirect(){
    window.location.href = "../index.html";
}`

Comment: I'm sorry the code I kept in comments is little confusing...I'm new to stack overflow so don't know how to send code properly @OliverRadini

Comment: @I'm_not_a_genius The best thing to do when the answer to one question does not solve your problem is to use another question - either ask a new one, or use an existing one. The most important thing is to fully understand what you're asking - very often the process of coming to a good question is the best way to solve the problem yourself anyway. I'm afraid I can't see what the problem is from the code in your comments